How to make a distributive union type that is compatible with `this` inside class methods in TypeScript?
I've been working with a distributive union type:
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;

type ValueOfUnion<T, K extends UnionKeys<T>> =
T extends infer U
  ? K extends keyof U
    ? T[K]
    : undefined
  : never;

This is then used to get type-safe access in a helper function:
function dig<T, K extends UnionKeys<T>>(
  obj: T, 
  key: K,
): ValueOfUnion<T, K> {
  return obj[key as keyof T] as any;
}

This works fine on "normal" objects, which may be unions:
type FooBar = {foo: string} | {bar: string};
const fooBar = {foo: 'foo'} as FooBar;
dig(fooBar, 'foo');

But it breaks when using this inside a class:
class FooBarHolder {
  public fooBar: FooBar;

  public doSomething() {
    // This is a trivial example, but imagine we have a deeply-
    // nested object where this is now non-trivial (also I know
    // the null-safe accessor could help here, but we use dig()
    // because the null-safe accessor doesn't play nicely with
    // code coverage)
    const fooBar = dig(this, 'fooBar') // doesn't work
  }
}

Playground
How do I make a distributive union type that plays nicely with this inside a class method as well as on a POJO?
(Sorry if this has already been asked; "this" is an exceptionally annoying keyword to search for)

Probably related: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16356

Why do you want it to be "distributive"? Do you expect this to be a union? Note that since this is implicitly generic inside a class, then this extends this ? true : false is a distributive type and therefore deferred until this is specified (such as when you have an actual instance of Test). What do you want this for? Why would you distribute over a class instance type which is rarely a union? Right now as this question as asked, the answer is "you can't". If you want an alternative, you should probably [edit] to explain your use case more. How would you like to proceed?

Edited to add motivation and further background.

This is looking more and more like an XY problem. That dig() function returns unknown for most things, is that the intent? There are all sorts of ways you could write dig() so that it behaves like that, none of which involve trying to force the this type to behave differently. See this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer if you first [edit] to make the question ask about the use case (Y) instead of the attempted solution (X). If not, what's missing?

Was trying to keep the question types simple, but I've added the correct return typing now.

Is this a [mre]? I see at least one typo in that code.  Please [edit] to fix those, try it in an IDE, you don't have to rush to update the question, just make sure your code is demonstrating what you intend before posting. ... And, assuming my guesses as to what your types should be are correct, my updated solutions for dig() look like this playground link, none of which are messing with this. So my question from the last comment stands.

Fair comment. I've updated the title to try to better reflect the question: it was more a question of compatibility with this rather then being for this. Your solution looks like it works! This is similar to my types before I started trying to mess with unions; I hadn't thought to just add an overload that looked like my old types!

• You've still got typos in there, could you please fix them? Try it in an IDE. As I said, you don't need to rush to edit the question, just make sure that when you do it's demonstrating what you intend (otherwise I get notified for every change and comment, and if it's still not an [mre] then I am personally involved in this part of the process when it's probably something you can and should do on your own). • Do you want me to write up an answer then? Or do you need to test things before you know?

Sorry I shouldn't multitask so much  Have tested and fixed typos (unless I pasted wrong...). The amount of type casting should probably have been a hint. Thanks for the patience/help. Writing up an answer would be nice, please!

You can't really write a distributive conditional type that is "compatible" with the polymorphic this type in the sense that it will recognize that this extends this ? true : false is true. That's because the polymorphic this type, as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#4910 is implicitly generic (an "implied type parameter" as mentioned in the PR description). And so that's a distributive conditional type and is thus deferred.  The type type Foo<T> = T extends T ? true : false is also going to be deferred until T is specified, because T is generic. There are various requests like microsoft/TypeScript#52144 to evaluate "obvious" things like this instead of deferring, but it's not part of the language as of TypeScript 5.6.
I'd say that you probably need to avoid "distributive union types" (assuming that has something to do with distributive conditional types) or only use them when you're sure the thing you're checking isn't generic. There are any number of ways to change dig() so that it behaves as you expect. An easy one is just to overload it so it uses T[K] directly when K extends keyof T:
function dig<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): T[K];
function dig<T, K extends UnionKeys<T>>(obj: T, key: K): ValueOfUnion<T, K>;
function dig(obj: any, key: PropertyKey) {
  return obj[key];
}

Now you get the following behavior
class FooBarHolder {
  public fooBar!: FooBar;

  public doSomething() {
    const fooBar = dig(this, 'fooBar');
    //    ^? const fooBar: this["fooBar"]
  }
}

}
which compiles and results in the this["fooBar"] type.  Note that this type isn't just FooBar, because this is still generic, and maybe a subclass of FooBarHolder will hold something narrower than FooBar, so TypeScript keeps that generic. If you want FooBar you can widen it manually, or widen this to FooBarHolder, or any number of other ways to avoid the fact that this is polymorphic to begin with.
Or you could collapse such an overload to a single call signature where K is constrained to the union of keyof T with UnionKeys<T>, so TypeScript can evaluate keyof this (which is not deferred) instead of UnionKeys<this> (which is deferred):
function dig<T, K extends keyof T | UnionKeys<T>>(obj: T, key: K): ValueOfUnion<T, K> {
  return obj[key] as any;
}

Or you could stop restricting K to UnionKeys<T> since apparently that will result in undefined and you don't really care about passing a key that isn't known to exist; if you can call dig(fooBar, "bar") when fooBar has no known bar property and get undefined, then it isn't necessarily any worse to call dig(fooBar, "baz"). In either case you're counting on the property to really be absent, even though it might not be (which is why unknown is the "right" type instead of undefined):
const hmm = { foo: "abc", bar: 123 };
const alsoHmm: FooBar = hmm;
const oops = dig(alsoHmm, "bar");
//    ^? const oops: undefined 
// OOPS, that undefined at compile time is number at runtime.

So you can always just make dig() accept all kinds of stuff, for all the good it does you:
function dig<T extends { [k: PropertyKey]: any }, K extends PropertyKey>(obj: T, key: K) {
  return (obj as any)[key] as ValueOfUnion<T, K>;
}

As mentioned above, there are all sorts of ways to work around the issue with this.  Whether any of these methods is the right one for your use case is probably out of scope here.
Playground link to code
